# find new exporting destinies: Data science - groupby and isin

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For the df below i want to discover the new destinies which these firms (`id` correspond to a firm) are exporting in 2016 in relation to 2015.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 
               "Year":[2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2015,2016,2016,2015,2016], 
               "Destiny":['A','B','A','B','C','D','C','C','D','A','Z']})
```

I thought in a `groupby` + `isin`, but couldn´t manage any hopefull approach

Output result should be:

```
 Id   Year   Destiny
 1    2016        D
 3    2016        Z
```

Comment: How does the output for this data look like?

Comment: D and Z should be the output result, which are destinies that had not been in 2015 but yes in 2016

Comment: Can you add the same in your question in the form of a dataframe?

Comment: @Dark there:)!!

Comment: Are there only 2 years in your dataset, or is this a simplified example?

Comment: there are more than 2 years, i wanted to simplified @BradSolomon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the Destinies which has 2015 i.e

```
to_remove = df[df['Year'].isin([2015])]['Destiny']

df[~df['Destiny'].isin(to_remove)]

   Destiny  Id  Year
5        D   1  2016
8        D   2  2016
10       Z   3  2016
```

Comment: Better is `df.loc[df['Year'].isin([2015]), 'Destiny']`

Comment: Or `df.loc[df['Year'] == 2015, 'Destiny']`

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Id','Year']).drop_duplicates(subset=['Id'], keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   Destiny  Id  Year
5        D   1  2016
8        D   2  2016
10       Z   3  2016
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please try this below code also:] please try this also:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 
           "Year":[2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2015,2016,2016,2015,2016], 
           "Destiny":['A','B','A','B','C','D','C','C','D','A','Z']})
df.groupby(["Id"]).last()
```